# Does the application GetMessage even during MessageBox?

Tags: windows, messagebox, reentrancy, getmessage

While handling WM_TIMER, I called **MessageBox**. As a result, a message box popped up with the frequency of the timer. So I believe that the application was trying to continue to process queued/non-queued messages even during **MessageBox**.

Am I right?

I know that according to MSDN, while an application is sending a message to a different thread from the sending thread, the sending thread will try to process  non-queued messages it receives before **SendMessage** returns --- i.e. before the target thread replies.

Are there any other functions that could try to continue to process queued/non-queued messages before they return, besides **MessageBox** and **SendMessage**? I need to know about that to determine whether any functions called in the Window procedure should be reentrant.

Another two relevant questions are
1) Does **DispatchMessage** not return until the window procedure has returned? 
2) Will **GetMessage** not be called again if the current **DispatchMessage** hasn't returned yet?

Comment: MessageBox runs in the same thread not a different thread so receiving WM_TIMER while messagebox is displayed is normal.

Answer (score 3):

A modal dialog runs its own message loop internally, using the calling thread's message queue.  You are calling `MessageBox()` inside your `WM_TIMER` handler, so the message loop inside of `MessageBox()` is receiving and dispatching subsequent `WM_TIMER` messages while the message box is running.